# Scraping Weather Data using regex in for loop

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

Trying to scrape barometric pressure 12 hours from now. Not sure how to modify my regex to capture the minute and hour that are found in two separate classes within 'td'.  I tried adding the class="ng-star-inserted"attribute to the find_all and searching for the hour but failed. Variable V is just a snippet of the parsed html using bs4. There are approximately two V like rows for every hour of the day.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import numpy as np
import cv2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import datetime
import os
import csv
import cefpython3 as cef
import sys
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

v = (
<tr _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-row ng-star-inserted" mat-header-row="" role="row">
 <!-- -->
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-timeHour mat-column-timeHour ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Time
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-conditions mat-column-conditions ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Conditions
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-temperature mat-column-temperature ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Temp.
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-feelsLike mat-column-feelsLike ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Feels Like
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-precipitation mat-column-precipitation ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Precip
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-liquidPrecipitation mat-column-liquidPrecipitation ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Amount
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-cloudCover mat-column-cloudCover ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Cloud Cover
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-dewPoint mat-column-dewPoint ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Dew Point
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-humidity mat-column-humidity ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Humidity
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-wind mat-column-wind ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Wind
 </th>
 <th _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-header-cell cdk-column-pressure mat-column-pressure ng-star-inserted" mat-header-cell="" role="columnheader">
  Pressure
 </th>
</tr>
<tr _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" mat-row="" role="row">
 <!-- -->
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-timeHour mat-column-timeHour ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   12
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="show-for-medium">
    :00
   </span>
   am
  </span>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-conditions mat-column-conditions ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <img _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="no-scale" src="//www.wunderground.com/static/i/c/v4/29.svg"/>
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="show-for-medium conditions">
    Partly Cloudy
   </span>
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="show-for-small-only conditions">
   </span>
  </span>
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-temperature mat-column-temperature ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test-true wu-unit wu-unit-temperature is-degree-visible ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     49
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      F
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-feelsLike mat-column-feelsLike ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test-true wu-unit wu-unit-temperature is-degree-visible ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     49
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      F
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-precipitation mat-column-precipitation ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <a _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted" href="/precipitation/us/or/portland">
   <!-- -->
   <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-chance ng-star-inserted">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
      0
     </span>
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
      <!-- -->
      <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
       %
      </span>
      <!-- -->
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </lib-display-unit>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-liquidPrecipitation mat-column-liquidPrecipitation ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <a _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted" href="/precipitation/us/or/portland">
   <!-- -->
   <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-rain ng-star-inserted">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
      0
     </span>
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
      <!-- -->
      <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
       in
      </span>
      <!-- -->
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </lib-display-unit>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-cloudCover mat-column-cloudCover ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-chance ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     31
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      %
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-dewPoint mat-column-dewPoint ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test-true wu-unit wu-unit-temperature is-degree-visible ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     44
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      F
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-humidity mat-column-humidity ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-humidity ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     81
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      %
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-wind mat-column-wind ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-speed ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     2
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      mph
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-suffix ng-star-inserted">
     NW
    </span>
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
 <td _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-pressure mat-column-pressure ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <lib-display-unit _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" _nghost-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   <!-- -->
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="test- wu-unit wu-unit-pressure ng-star-inserted">
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-value wu-value-to">
     30.05
    </span>
    <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="wu-label">
     <!-- -->
     <span _ngcontent-app-root-c15="" class="ng-star-inserted">
      in
     </span>
     <!-- -->
    </span>
    <!-- -->
   </span>
   <!-- -->
  </lib-display-unit>
  <!-- -->
 </td>
</tr>
)

time_12 = '8:27'

userInputDt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_12, '%H:%M')

for row in v:
    m = re.findall('(\d+:\d+)\s+([AP]M)', row.get_text())
    if len(m) > 0:
        dtString = ' '.join(map(str,m[0]))
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtString, '%I:%M %p')
        timedelta = abs(dt - userInputDt)
        if time_delta == None or timedelta < time_delta:
            save_row = row
            time_delta = timedelta
z = []

for td in save_row.find_all('td'):
        z.append(td.get_text())
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\test2.py", line 57, in <module>
    for td in save_row.find_all('td'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

script fails at

```
m = re.findall('(\d+:\d+)\s+([AP]M)', row.get_text())
```

I believe I need to combine the hour and minute from the html into one string before the regex will work, but not sure how to proceed.

```
timeHour ng-star-inserted" mat-cell="" role="gridcell">
  <!-- -->
  <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="ng-star-inserted">
   12
   <span _ngcontent-app-root-c5="" class="show-for-medium">
    :00
   </span>
```

Actual source code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import numpy as np
import cv2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
import datetime
import os
import csv
import cefpython3 as cef
import sys
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

now = datetime.datetime.now()
now_plus_12 = now + datetime.timedelta(hours = 12)
future_12 = (now_plus_12.timetuple())
fTup12 = str(future_12[0]),str(future_12[1]),str(future_12[2]),str(future_12[3]),str(future_12[4])
fList12 = list(fTup12)
year = fList12[0]
month = fList12[1]
day = fList12[2]
timeTup = str(fList12[3]),str(fList12[4])
timeList = list(timeTup)
time_12 = ':'.join(timeList)

opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.maximize_window()

weather_url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/us/or/portland/date/' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day
driver.get(weather_url)
time.sleep(20)
weather_html = driver.page_source
weather_soup = soup(weather_html, "html.parser")
table = weather_soup.find('table', id="hourly-forecast-table")

save_row = None
time_delta = None

#userInputDt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_12, '%H:%M')

#for row in table.find_all('tr'):
 #   m = re.findall('(\d+:\d+)\s+([AP]M)', row.get_text())
  #  if len(m) > 0:
   #     dtString = ' '.join(map(str,m[0]))
    #    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtString, '%I:%M %p')
     #   timedelta = abs(dt - userInputDt)
      #  if time_delta == None or timedelta < time_delta:
       #     save_row = row
        #    time_delta = timedelta
#v = []

#for td in save_row.find_all('td'):
 #       v.append(td.get_text())
```

Comment: This is a angular app that's getting json data from a XHR, so you should just use that.

Comment: What kind of of variable is v (what type, initialized how) ? I'm guessing you didn't set it like in your code sample.

Comment: Can you include the source url?

Comment: weather_url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/us/or/portland/date/2019-10-14'

Comment: v is just an snippet of output from    weather_soup.find('table', id="hourly-forecast-table")

Comment: It's an hourly table, so shouldn't the minutes always be 00

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the HTML source changed from upper case AM/PM to lower case am/pm

changed

```
m = re.findall('(\d+:\d+)\s+([AP]M)', row.get_text())
```

to

```
m = re.findall('(\d+:\d+)\s+([ap]m)', row.get_text())
```